# PHP array of folders in directory and show files in each folder

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I am using the following code to list all folders in a directory (called test), and all files within those folders:

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
$ffs = scandir($dir);
echo '<ol>';
foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        echo '<li class="title">'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('test');

?>
```

This works fine, however I want to be able to link to each file in those folders. Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

For example I have a directory called "test" with subdirectories "test 1", "test 2" and "test 3". In each of those I have a couple of files that I would like to be links that a user can click on to show the file. So when a user goes to the site they will see something like this:

Test 1:
link 1
link 2

Test 2:
link 1
link 2

Test 3:
link 1 
link 2

Comment: I suggest doing this recursively. Take a look at [`DirectoryIterator` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: What do you mean by `link to each file in those folders` can you give example ?

Comment: Just added an example. See description

Comment: @Baba I think he wants something like this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/192101-listing-contents-of-a-folder-on-a-webpage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a html A tag inside the LI tag you are outputting. Something along these lines should work:

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="title">';
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                echo $ff;
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }else{
                echo '<a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}


listFolderFiles('test');

?>
```

Comment: This has worked quite nicely, however, it turns EVERYTHING into a link, including the folder name. I just want the files in the folder to be a link. So I need to somehow separate out the folder name from the files.

Comment: I've made a quick and dirty edit which should do the trick I think. The new line just checks if the file name is the same as the directory name so it may not work in all circumstances

Comment: That didn't seem to display anything for me. Is there a way of just echoing the subdirectory name, and then echoing all the files in that directory as links?

Comment: Okay Sam, try it now. I've made some edits with better logic.

Comment: Brilliant. That worked perfectly. Is there anyway to separate out the subdirectory name into its on li class??

Comment: It would start to get much more complicated if you wanted to do that as the current function doesn't know directories from subdirectories. You could look at using a class like the ones listed in the comments above.

Comment: If you wanted to try it yourself, try adding a second variable called $depth to the function and increment it each time the function is called. You could then use `class='title'.$depth`, which would give you unique classes for each subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks @cronoklee can you perhaps provide an example?