# Array of folders in directory and show files in each folder, rename/delete option

Tags: php, arrays, directory, delete-file, file-rename

This is a follow up question to [a thread I came across here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876455/php-array-of-folders-in-directory-and-show-files-in-each-folder).

Users can upload pictures to my site, and they are saved in an 'uploads' folder. Another page on the site has a photo gallery that pulls pictures from an 'approved' folder. How do I go about including a link (or checkbox) to rename or delete each file, after the file name? i.e.:

```
    <?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                echo '<li class="title">';
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                    echo $ff;
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                }else{
                    echo '<a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>'.
                    '...<a href="rename.file">Keep</a> - 
                    <a href="delete.file">Delete</a>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }


listFolderFiles('uploaded_files');

?>
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @SKRocks Currently the code just lists all the files within the 'uploaded_files' folder. I want to have links after each file that will Keep (rename the file to /approved/file_name) or Delete the file from the server all together.

Comment: have you try anything so far? put some effort search something `how to delete file using php` and `how to rename file using php` you will find a lot of. try that in your code first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete a file from a directory using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338851/how-to-delete-a-file-from-a-directory-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="title">';
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                echo $ff;
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }else{
                echo '<a href="delete.php?file='.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>';
                echo '<a href="rename.php?file='.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}


listFolderFiles('uploaded_files');

?>
```

In **delete.php**, take the File Argument $_GET['file'];

```
<?php

$file = "root/".$_GET['file'];
unlink($file);
location('back to the page');

?>
```

In **rename.php** get the new name and

```
<?php

    $file = "root/".$_GET['file'];
    rename($file,"New file name");
    location('back to the page');

?>
```

Now there are two ways to going about, Use ajax in main page or in rename.php take the new file name as input and do renaming.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can get it from there.